Biophysics for longevity research? Does the undergraduate background matter for US graduate programs?
I am currently studying undergraduate physics (condensed matter) (outside the US).
Starting from the beginning of the 3rd year of studies, there'll be an opportunity to publish undergraduate research publications
Seriously considering changing my current major to biophysics, because I want to pursue masters/PhD in the field that focuses on epigenetics and longevity, anyway.
But, I am not sure. There are a couple of ideas in condensed matter, that I'd like to try out
So, the options are:

Finish the current physics bachelor major -> Apply to Biophysics PhD in the US

Undergraduate research will not be related to longevity, or biology for that matter. But more to materials science. Recommendation letters would mostly be from condensed matter researchers

Switch to biophysics bachelors and graduate -> Apply to Biophysics PhD in the US

There's an option of longevity and epigenetics for undergraduate research. And that research would be more relevant to the desired PhD. I'd be able to get recommendations and connections in field

Finish undergraduate physics -> masters Biophysics -> Biophysics PhD in the US

Basically get to try out the ideas in condensed matter, and if none of them kick in then go to masters, get all the benefits of the 2nd option. But It'll take 2 years longer. Also if your application in the 4th year of your bachelors, is not strong enough for your desired graduate programs, then you could try to create even stronger application while studying for your masters.
The reason I am not sure, is that If one goes with the 1st option, with background of condensed matter, that applicant may stand out from the overall applicant pool (an advantage). However, the person will not have research experience, relevant to the PhD (a disadvantage? The same but reverse, with the 2nd option
How does the undergraduate major and undergraduate research, affect the admission to US graduate programs in life sciences?

Your interest in epigenetics suggests more than passing acquaintance with molecular biology, genetics, and maybe statistical genetics. Good luck!

@Aruralreader Thanks!

Have you considered finish physics undergrad and find a seminar series on your topic of interest to attend while doing this? Physicists have skills and ways of thinking that biologists lack. I've had one or two friends who did biophysics and ended up feeling they didn't get to learn the biology or the physics in great detail and doing a degree in one of them would have been better (unless you can find a way to double major so you have expertise in both).

@NAMcMahon Will consider this option, but because the curriculum schedules and courses for my major are hard set and not really flexible, it'd be difficult to do so. But I'll try

I'm not talking about a seminar series course, but talking about finding a research group working on something related and see if they have a colloquium/weekly meeting (one where someone always presents their work, not a general group meeting) that you could attend if it doesn't line up with a course you are taking. That would allow you to both network and learn the terms and what people think are important in that field.

@NAMcMahon I actually attended a meeting like this and connected to 2 people in the field. 1 is the head of a bioinformatics lab (protein folding), the 2nd studies copper metabolism and its connection to Wilson's disease. But they said that it'd be more preferable to just switch major, because of the courses and because the physics department would have a hard time accepting my biology related undergraduate thesis

My close friend is a professor and the head of a lab at a very good university in the Boston area. He has a triple appointment, being simultaneously affiliated with the departments of mechanical engineering, physics, and biomedical engineering.
His field may be broadly defined as biomedical physics. On more than one occasion, my friend told me that when considering application from potential PhD students, he first of all makes sure that a candidate has taken all the intermediate courses in physics -- that is a key parameter.  Although my friend considers applications from students with various backgrounds, he prefers to take people majoring in physics.  And it should not necessarily be biophysics.  E.g. a couple of years ago, he took a young man who had a Masters in condensed matter physics.  That young man knew next to nothing about biology, but is now doing extremely well and will receive his PhD in a year.  As my friend said, it is much easier for a physicist to learn biology than for a biologist to learn physics.
You are welcome to write to me if you wish, and I shall refer you to my friend's webpage. Perhaps, you will want then to talk to him directly. My e-mail address is available at my website.

"Biophysics PhD" is still quite a broad description. This could be anything, really.
Since you mention epigenetics and longevity, it seems you have a very clear niche in mind. What type of research would you like to do in that context? Are you also thinking bench work or only computational?
Ultimately it depends on how fast and how much you want to redirect towards yourself towards answering biological questions. This doesn't even have to be during your PhD, it could also still mean a switch after.
Planning these things solely based on what looks good/best on paper is not necessarily the best life choice, so also consider what you like and find interesting.
Maybe option 2 allows you to test the waters in the areas you now think you want to get a PhD in. Maybe you will like it, maybe you won't. Better to know before the start of a PhD, so internships are great for that.
Option 3 will likely be dictated by personal circumstances, whether you can financially afford two extra years of training, etc.
If you can, talk to different people in the field you are in now and the field you think you want to go into (both junior and senior). They will have the most relevant real world advise.


"What type of research would you like to do in that context".

I am not sure at this point. Probably chemical reprogramming and drug delivery.

"Are you also thinking bench work or only computational?"

Yeah, I could do bench work. But primarily interested working in a wet lab.
Overall, I believe that aging is a big problem, worth studying. Although I've heard that, Biotech as a whole offers lower pay and demands longer working hours compared to other industries. And money and financial security are actually important as well.

chemical reprogramming and drug delivery seems quite far removed from epigenetic and more towards a (bio)chemical angle. In either case, it sounds like you would benefit from a solid background in molecular biology (including (epi)genetics and biochemistry) in that case.
You may want to begin monitoring for positions in the area you are interested in right now - in Europe positions are often advertised by individual labs. See what's asked in terms of background for areas you are interested in. Then again, it could very well be that the "job and background of the future" doesn't exist yet.

If you are primarily interested in working in a wet lab, then you will want to develop wet lab skills (that's what I meant with "bench work"). Of course you could be "the computational person" in a wet lab, but if you yourself want to do experiments, then you'll want to get proper training in that at some point - either before, during or after the PhD.
I would encourage you to seek out local advisors to discuss different options. In the end it is about finding what you like and how you measure up against the competition once you apply to programs you are interested in.

Ok, Now I understand more, thanks!

For US students, changing fields between undergraduate and graduate study is common. For those who want a career in academia, the usual approach is to apply to doctoral programs in the last year of undergraduate studies. However, this is enabled by the nature of the undergraduate program, which is quite broad here. A typical program is only about 40% or so in the major. So, a math or physics student will also have courses in history, writing, literature, philosophy (perhaps), and many others. Even within a field, the education tends to be broad, covering many of the important sub-fields rather than concentrating on one. There might be an opportunity for some low level research along the way, but not many get an opportunity for anything serious due to time constraints and the  open ended nature of research. Relatively few US undergraduate students have publications at graduation for that reason and also the delays in the publication process. Having publications is a plus, but not an essential element for entry to graduate programs.
For a foreign student, things are more complicated since many programs outside the US are much more focused on one field making familiarity with other fields less common. It is one reason that undergraduate programs are typically longer here than elsewhere.
So, if your current program has no opportunity to look at biology and its methods then it will be harder to switch as you might be seen as lacking the necessary background. If you try to enter already having a masters that includes no biology then it will be harder (and a longer path) but not necessarily impossible.
Note also that US doctoral programs don't have an unlimited number of seats available and there is competition for them, so you need to be seen as a good candidate for success in a new field. Highly rated programs are also selective in who they admit. It is considered a waste of time and effort to admit students to doctoral programs who aren't very likely to succeed.
So, while nothing is impossible, the earlier you get familiarity with basic ideas of a new field, the more likely you are to be accepted, and the more likely you are to know you have chosen a good path.
This suggests that 3 is likelier than 1 to reach the point of acceptance. Your 2 might work but would also probably delay graduation.

So What you are saying is that doing the longevity related work, prior to PhD, would make the PhD application more competitive? There's no organic chemistry or biology in the coursework of my current major.

Making a radical switch with no background in the new field is an issue. And, while physics isn't my field, condensed matter to genetics seems like a long jump, both conceptually and in research process. See: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368

Ok, Now it is more clear. Thank you
